# How to get one or more data when we do click in checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a problem , when i do click on one or select all , all data coming. But i need when I click on single checkbox then only that particular data should come.

> html file

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Student Information</h1>
                <table id="example" class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Siblling</th>
                        <th>select all <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.selectAll()"/></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in vm.data">
                        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.mobileNumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.isMigrated}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.selected" class="duplicateRow" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>

                    <button class="button pull-right"  ng-click="vm.process()">Process</button>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <pagination ng-if="renderpagination" page-number='{{vm.pageNumber}}' page-count="{{vm.pageCount}}" total-records="{{vm.totalRecords}}" api-url="duplicate-student"></pagination>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
           </div>
        </div>
```

> Java script file

```
vm.selectAll =function(){
      angular.forEach(vm.data, function(data){
       data.selected=true;
      });
    }
    vm.selectedUsers = [];

    vm.process = function() {
      vm.selectedUsers.splice(0, vm.selectedUsers.length);
      for (var i in vm.data) {
           vm.selectedUsers.push(vm.data[i]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: `ng-click="vm.selectAll()"` should be `ng-change="vm.selectAll()"` and i dont see any method call for single checkbox.

Comment: can you provide plnkr for this ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe3rwgfx/) with part of your code and everything works as expected.

Comment: where you are suppose to get the selected data?

Comment: problem is all data coming at a time if i select one row also, if you do "console.log("response::"+JSON.stringify(vm.selectedUsers))"

Comment: and ng-change not working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link may what your looking for : [Angular Checkboxes “Select All” functionality with only one box selected initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451954/angular-checkboxes-select-all-functionality-with-only-one-box-selected-initial)
.